# C++: Is it legal to declare a method virtual in a derived class when it wasn't virtual in the base?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

The base class specifically declares the method to be non-virtual. 
It works in Visual Studio 2008,2010 and 2012 and [whatever compiler ideone uses](http://ideone.com/D8rbcH) (gcc 4.7+ ?).

```
#include <iostream>

class sayhi
{
public:
    void hi(){std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;}
};

class greet: public sayhi
{
public:
    virtual void hi(){std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;}
};


int main()
{
    greet noob;
    noob.hi(); //Prints hello world
    return 0;
}
```

This works too - the method is private and non-virtual in the base class:

```
#include <iostream>

class sayhi
{
private:
    void hi(){std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;}
};

class greet: public sayhi
{
public:
    virtual void hi(){std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;}
};


int main()
{
    greet noob;
    noob.hi(); //Prints hello world
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it legal?
2. Why does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1 . Is it legal?

**Yes**.

> 2 . Why does it work?

Nothing prevents you from declaring a member function in a derived class that has the same name as a member function of the base class. Your function in the derived class will simply **hide** the function of the base class. Incidentally, if the function from the derived class happens to be `virtual`, then subclasses may override it:

```
class howdy : public greet
{
public:
    // Overrides greet::hi()
    virtual void hi() { std::cout << "howdy world" << std::endl; }
};
```

This, however, does not affect the `sayhi::hi()` in any way: in particular, the mere presence of a `virtual` function in a derived class that hides it **does not make it** `virtual`. Therefore, you cannot expect virtual dispatch to work while invoking the function through a pointer or reference to an instance of the *base* class `sayhi`:

```
sayhi noob;
noob.hi(); // Will NOT print "hello world"!

greet gentleman;
sayhi* p = &gentleman;
p->hi(); // Will NOT print "hello world"!

howdy neighbor;
p = &neighbor; 
p->hi(); // Will NOT print "howdy"!

greet* pG = &neighbor;
pG->hi(); // WILL print "howdy"!
```

Answer (score 2):

It's legal. The method becomes `virtual` from that point on in derived classes of `greet`.

The base class method is hidden (as would happen with a non-`virtual`).

Calling the method through a `greet` pointer will resolve the call dynamically. Calling it through a `sayhi` will resolve it statically.

Take, for example:

```
class sayhi
{
public:
    void hi(){std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;}
};

class greet: public sayhi
{
public:
    virtual void hi(){std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;}
};

class greetuniverse: public greet
{
public:
    virtual void hi(){std::cout<<"hello universe"<<std::endl;}
};
```

The following

```
sayhi* p = new greetuniverse;
p->hi();
```

will print `hello` because `hi` isn't virtual in `sayhi`. However

```
greet* p = new greetuniverse;
p->hi();
```

will print `hello universe` because the method is called dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It is legal. By naming a function in the derived class virtual you are telling the compiler at run time to check the method of the derived class for the implementation of the function before going to the base class.